# Unable to add response.write() in action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Am trying to download bulk excel data so am using server.mappath() to save the file but problem is file is downloaded to the specific folder but i didn't get the download file in the browser. so how to add an response.write to in ASP.NET MVC

Calling CreateExcelDocument method:

```
string worksheet_name = "RetailerReport.xls";
string MyDocumentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
          Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(ds, MyDocumentsPath + "\\" + worksheet_name);
```

CreateExcelDocument method:

```
public static bool CreateExcelDocument(DataSet ds, string excelFilename)
{
    try
    {

        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(
            excelFilename, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            WriteExcelFile(ds, document);
        }
        Trace.WriteLine("Successfully created: " + excelFilename);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Failed, exception thrown: " + ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

After creation of excel file i want to add response.write

Comment: do you mean that you need to download the created Excel file to the client machine?

Comment: Very unclear how this code relates to problem (as it seem to be client side)... Plus post does not shows all research author should have done as there are thousands of "how to write code to download file" for bot server and client parts... Showing [MCVE] could help...